# How to render ultra-realistic looking models and textures in Blender?

Tags: rendering, texturing, lighting, photorealism

I know I know, I sculpt a model, bake the textures >apply them and that's it.

Come on, that can not be everything when it comes to ultra-realistic 3d models.

I have seen guys creating textures with applying 102381028310 stuff, like sub-surface scattering, then some extra layers of textures, once zoomed in, a user can see more textres that are like small and normally not rendered from far away.

Can you just make a list of such things that would not be included in the >bake them, difuse, AO, spec normal maps> apply them and that's it.

So any extra technique that you know, please post it. Yes I know lightning is important but that is a whole different question. haha I probably sound a little bit irritated in this question, that is because I already asked in like 5 forums and no one is able to tell me some of the other techniques or whatever, so that I know where to expand my knowledge.

Comment: What kind of models? Humans? Animals? Items? Flowers?

Comment: anmatomy muscles and bones... no muddy old horror type of skeletons. Nice healthy bones wet and clean, freshly out of the body.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry if you've been rebutted many times but this question is definitely too broad for this site, please try to restrict your queries. It will aslo help you achieve your goal since photorealism is not a one-button magic trick, you have to study your subject under many aspects to fully grasp what makes it believable. Color, composition, materials, scale, storyboard, grunge, etc.

Comment: but where would one start?! It's like telling me go and study medicine... Eventually you start with anatomy and physiology and then you move to pathology etc...

Comment: There's no magic trick, the question is way way too broad. No one is able to give a simple direct answer because it involves too many things. You have to start from the basics and build up. As they say, there's two type of unknowns: known unknowns (things you know you don't know) and uknown unknowns (things you don't even know are a thing so you don't know you don't know them). As you learn from the basics and build up, you'll start to find out the things you don't know, and you can go after learning them.

Comment: I would recommend you look for good online courses that cover anatomy, modeling/sculpting and shading/lighting/render. Doesn't have to be everything in the same course, in fact you won't easily find a single course that covers everything - I would recommend starting from an anatomy course, then modeling/sculpting, etc

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create realistic humans you should first study anatomy. Really study it, learn the bones, the muscles, etc. Learn to draw the human figure.
Then learn the sculpting tools in Blender (or another sculpting software like Zbrush, obviously, but this is a Blender forum so I'll stick to blender).
If you want to work in real productions, also learn retopology. Learn modeling fundamentals. Learning hard surface modeling would be good too.
Learn how to open UVs in an efficient way. Learn how to texture the models. Study how real light behaves and how it bounces off different materials. Understand subsurface scattering (really important for humans).
Learn to create and groom realistic hair and fur.
Learn how to create good lighting, like a photographer or cinematographer would. You also need to learn the render settings and what each setting does.

So basically:

1. Anatomy and figure drawing
2. Sculpting in 3D software
3. 3D Modeling fundamentals (organic and hard surface)
4. Retopology
5. Opening UVs
6. Optics (how light behaves and interacts with different materials)
7. Editing physically based shaders
8. Hair and fur
9. Lighting and Render

I think that's about it.

I recommend this series of videos to start studying anatomy: https://youtu.be/pDgyQjNFVQk

Comment: wow!! Finally! Thanks a lot !!! I will use this as an overview to plan what I am going to study in the upcoming months. Thank you so much!